# Cannot set DataContext of custom UserControl declaratively

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have created a small UserControl named EventMenu.  I reference it in a larger view using:

```
 <views:EventMenu 
     Grid.Row="1" 
     DataContext="{Binding DataContext.ServicingEventsMenuViewModel}"
  />
```

(I've also tried `DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext.ServicingEventsMenuViewModel}"`).

However, no content from the bound data context appears in the control (static content from the control's XAML file does appear).  I believe the control is not binding the DataContext.

In the code behind constructor for the UserControl, I've done this:

```
    public EventMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (DataContext == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No data context!");
        }
    }
```

and it does indicate that the DataContext is null.

What do I need to do to ensure that the DataContext is set on my UserControl?

Comment: Does larger view's DataContext have property `ServicingEventsMenuViewModel`?

Comment: @LarryLustig if it contains `ServicingEventsMenuViewModel` property then most likely you don't need `DataContext` part in binding path. Basically in your case it will try to find property like this `DataContext.DataContext.ServicingEventsMenuViewModel` as it will try to take given path from current `DataContext` property value

Comment: also for any failure relating to Binding, you can view the Output window to see if there is any error reported there.

Comment: @Rothit: Yes, the outer view's context does have ServicingEventsMenuViewModel; and after creating this model in the outer view's constructor I perform IndicatePropertyChanged on it.

Comment: @KingKing: Nothing in the output window other than the message I'm writing myself.

Answer (score 0):

The first wrong thing i see is this :

```
   DataContext="{Binding DataContext.ServicingEventsMenuViewModel}"
```

DataContext is a Dependency Property of FrameworkElement.

So when writing something like you'v written , you wrote it as if your DataContext had a property called DataContext , it's the equivalent of writing this :

```
  DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext.ServicingEventsMenuViewModel}"
```

Are you trying to reach a parent element's DataContext ? 
if so you need to write something like this ( for example if it's parent is a UserControl):

```
  DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext.ServicingEventsMenuViewModel,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}"
```

I'm guessing that's the case here ...

let me ask you this , post the xaml in which

```
  <views:EventMenu />
```

is nested and the class holding ServicingEventsMenuViewModel property .

The second thing i think is wrong is to checking if your DataContext is null in the constructor , even if you did write the correct binding statement this property would still be null in the constructor.

subscribe to the FrameworkElement's Loaded event and check it there.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried first with the `Path` construct with identical results.  The view model I want to set as the DataContext of my nested UserControl is a property of the DataContext of the outer view -- I do not need to reach back an additional level.  My control is nested in a very large XAML file (which was given to me, and which I'm trying to refactor into smaller pieces).  I will attempt to create a minimal example when I am working on this tomorrow.

Comment: you need the one with relativesource and you do not need the DataContext in the path